# Html Form not passing image file name to laravel controller

Tags: html, laravel

Laravel Blade Form not passing image . it comes out null but other  types are passed.
this is the form;

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form method="POST" action="{{route('slide.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Slide Title" name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Slide Description" name="description">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" >Image</label>
            <input type="file"  name="image">
        </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

this is the controller store function;

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request->all();
    $product = New Slide($request->except(['image']));
        $product->save();
        //store image
        if($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()){
            $product->addMediaFromRequest('image')->toMediaCollection('images/slides');
        }
        return redirect("slide/index/{$product->id}")->with('success', 'New Slide Added.');
}
```

and this is the route;

```
Route::resource('slide', 'SlideController');
```

I have included the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` already. I cant see what am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think `Route::resource('slide', 'SlideController');` should be like this `Route::resource('user', 'UserController')->names(['store' => 'slide.store']);` And you have write **return** statement at very first line of store() method. Can you please share what is your actual problem? `$product->addMediaFromRequest('image')->toMediaCollection('images/slides');` Possible to share this function's body.

Comment: @SiddharajsinhZala, the <b>return</b> statement is to check the values returned. the problem is that the image is not passed along with others